# compare objects like primitive types in java

Tags: java, compare, comparable

thinking of the way implementing the Iterable interface lets clients iterate over *something* in your class with a foreach loop, is there a way to allow object comparison by <, > == etc.?
It seems almost obvious to let the Comparable interface allow for this, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do this as Java doesn't support operator overloading.

Comment: Well that was a quick answer.
Thank you :)
Too bad though, it would have been awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

it is trivial to translate `a<b` to `a.compareTo(b)<0`

but there is no option for operator overloading

not to mention how would the nulls be handled

Comment: Oh, and sure it is, but it's inelegant as hell :)